# VBA with Excel getElementById not working after upgrade to IE11 - Getting Run-time error 424

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

The following code works fine on older versions of Internet Explorer, but fails on Windows 10 and IE11. I get a Run-Time error 424 on the first getElementById command below. Nothing in the code changed except for the upgrade to IE11. Any ideas?

```
 Option Explicit

 Public Sub Get_Case_By_DateRange()

 Dim elems
 Dim e

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

   IE.document.getElementById("NewProperty").selectedindex = 51   <-- Fails 
   IE.document.getElementById("NewRelation").selectedindex = 5
```

Comment: How are you creating the `IE` object?

Comment: Some preliminary questions: **1)** If you are on Windows 10 then you can't have "upgraded to IE11", because Windows 10 only comes with IE11 and Edge. So either you are not on Windows 10, or you did not "just" upgrade to IE11- you upgraded Operating Systems. Can you clarify the situation here? **2)** Have you run IE11 yet on the machine? There are some first-time use thing that can break VBA code from running. **3)** Do you have the requisite References checked? I believe they are Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Comment: Tyler, I moved this code from an old laptop to a new laptop with Windows 10 and IE11.  I have run IE11 on the machine, but not with any VBA code, just for browsing. I don't know about #3. I'll have to research it because I don't understand the question. Still pretty green with VBA programming.

Comment: @VBAnewguy In the VBA Editor there's a Menu option called Tools; the first option under Tools is a feature called References. There are a lot of things VBA can accomplish, but you often need to make sure you are including references to the right libraries, first. This is just like "Using" statements in ASP.NET code (for example). However, I see you use `IE.readyState`. Consider [switching to onLoad](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/bg182625(v=vs.85)#legacy-api-additions-changes-and-removals) instead; `readyState` may not work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to the readystate. I commented out that code and put in a 15 second delay to wait for the webpage to load and it gave me the 424 error again. It died on the getElementById statement.

Comment: Also, I verified the References and they were NOT checked, so I checked them and got the same error.

Comment: Got it. I added the url to the Compatibility View List in IE11. Worked like usual after that. @TylerH, thanks for your help.

Comment: @VBAnewguy Great! I would recommend adding what you did as an answer below, and then marking it as the Accepted Answer, to let future readers know what the solution was for you.